# Convergent series: am I doing it right?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{5k-2}{(3{k}^{2}-2)\sqrt[3]{k+6}}
$$
I get (i did not write all solution as it is quite hard to me to put this in LaTeX by myself)
$$
\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \frac{{a}_{k+1}}{{a}_{k}}=...=\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\frac{15{k}^{3\frac{1}{3}}}{30{k}^{3\frac{1}{3}}}=\frac{3}{10}
$$
As $$\frac{3}{10}<1$$ series is convergent.

Is that right?

Comment: Your reasoning is wrong. As the other answerer suggests, the ratio test will be inconclusive. A good apporach would probably be limit comparison test. I hint that $1-2-\frac{1}{3}< -1$, so... Then all you have to do is "formalize" the bounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to use the comparison test. For the comparison test to work we need to be aware of a well known series with which to compare the given series. In this direction we will use the following standard result:

*The series $$\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{k^{p}}$$ is convergent if $p > 1$ and divergent if $p \leq 1$.*

This result itself can be proved using Cauchy-Maclaurin Integral test or Cauchy Condensation test.

Now we can informally check that for given series $\sum a_{k}$, $$a_{k} = \frac{5k-2}{(3{k}^{2}-2)\sqrt[3]{k+6}} \approx \dfrac{5k}{3k^{2}\cdot k^{1/3}} = \frac{5}{3k^{4/3}}$$ Let $b_{k} = 1/k^{4/3}$ so that $\sum b_{k}$ is convergent (from the result in italics above with $p = 4/3$). Clearly $$\lim_{k \to \infty}\frac{a_{k}}{b_{k}} = \frac{5}{3} \neq 0$$ (this limit needs to be evaluated properly in an exam, the above informal approximation shows why it should be $5/3$). Hence by comparison test the behavior of both series $\sum a_{k}$ and $\sum b_{k}$ is same with regard to convergence. It follows now that the given series $\sum a_{k}$ is convergent.

Answer (score 0):

No, the ratio test should give you a $1$ in this case.

Comment: Can you please write a correct solution?

Comment: No, I am sorry. For your own good, I suggest you first identify where you went wrong with your ratio test solution. Then, try other methods and see if you can work the problem out with them. If not, please ask a new question on this same series again (do not edit this one). As a hint, note that the terms are roughly $k^{-4/3}$ for large $k$, and hence your series will converge.

Answer (score 0):

@John, if you need further advice, try the following bounds: $5k-2<5k$, $(k+6)^{1/3} > k^{1/3}$ and $3k^{2} - 2 > 3(k-1)^{2}$ $\forall k>1$. Why am I only applying this bound for $k>1$? Now the problem reduces to showing what's happening with $(\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{5k^{2/3}}{3(k-1)^{2}}) + \frac{3}{7^{1/3}}$. Now, this solution will pretty much write itself. But, first, you should really figure out what when wrong when you did the ratio test.